# A diagonalizable $3\times3$ matrix with precisely two real eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I'm wondering, does there exist a diagonalizable $3\times3$ matrix that has precisely two real eigenvalues? I thought that there doesn't because in order for a matrix to be diagonalizable, the number of eigenvalues has to equal to the dimension of the matrix. I know that it might work with complex numbers but if no complex numbers are allowed in the matrix, then would a matrix like that exist using only real numbers?

Comment: It is simply not true that the number of eigenvalues must match the dimension of the space on which the matrix acts. The proper statement is that the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces must equal the dimension of the whole space.

Comment: Ok so then if you can't find 3 eigenvectors, the matrix is non-diagnolizable. So there's another 3x3 matrix that has nothing but 2's in it. I found the eigenvalues to be 0 and 6. So you'd assume that because there's only two eigenvalues, there's only 2 eigenvectors but I found out that there does exist 3 eigenvectors even with only 2 distinct eigenvalues. So how would that work?

Comment: Once you have any eigenvector, you have infinitely many of them (all its non-zero scalar multiples), so please don't say things like "there exist only $2$ eigenvectors".  What you probably mean is a _linearly independent set_ of eigenvectors; for that case the maximal number is the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces. But one can talk about that sum of dimensions without having to mention linearly independent eigenvectors, which is what I did in my first comment. And in any case the _number of eigenvalues_, which is just the number of different eigenspaces, is a different notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on how you choose to count the eigenvalues:

If you simply want the number of distinct real eigenvalues, then the answer to your question is yes: take any diagonal $3\times 3$ matrix with only two distinct diagonal entries. For instance,
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

If you want the number of real eigenvalues counted with multiplicity, then the answer is no: the characteristic polynomial of a real $3\times 3$ matrix is a real polynomial of degree $3$, and therefore has either $1$ or $3$ real roots if these roots are counted with multiplicity. In the above example, the multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is $2$.

Comment: But that matrix is already in diagonal form. What would be the original matrix? Also that diagonal matrix suggest that the 1 appears twice. Would it still be considered only 2 eigenvalues if the 1 appears twice?

Comment: Any diagonal matrix is diagonalizable. For your second question, it depends how you count the eigenvalues. If the eigenvalues are counted with multiplicity, then the above matrix has 3 real eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. I don't want a diagonal matrix, I want a normal matrix A in $ℝ^3$ that can be turned into a diagonal matrix by finding a B matrix such that $B^{-1}AB = D$ where D is a diagonal matrix that lists out the eigenvalues in increasing order while going down the diagonal.

Comment: A diagonal matrix *is* a "normal" matrix. Take $B$ to be the identity matrix.

Comment: Ok what about a 3x3 matrix that only has 2's in it. It has the eigenvalues 0, 6 and it does have 3 eigenvectors so would that mean that matrix is diagonalizable and has 2 eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @davidmah Take any nonsingular matrix $B$ and compute $BDB^{-1}$. Now you’ve got a “normal” matrix with the same eigenvalues as the diagonal matrix that you started with (and you already know its eigenvectors).

Answer (score 0):

I think the bit you are missing is that the characteristic equation has to have three real roots, and there must be 3 linearly independent eigenvectors.

So the characteristic equation could be in the form $(1-λ)^{2}(2-λ)$ which technically has only two roots but still has three linearly independent eigenvectors.